# Store strings as DIFFERENT variables on each trial

Tags: java, android

I have a request that is quite curious, as most people have never dealt with this issue.

Every time my app runs, I get a value, say `ScoreActivity.score` (Where `ScoreActivity` is the activity in which the value comes up, and `score` is the actual value). Every time I reach this certain activity, say `ResultActivity`, I need to store `ScoreActivity.score` as a variable. I have accomplished this by

```
int var1 = ScoreActivity.score
```

Now, here's the problem. I would like `ScoreActivity.score` to be stored as a different variable every time the user does this game. So say that the user goes through the game, gets a `score` at `ScoreActivity`, and moves to the `ResultActivity` page. I would like this `ScoreActivity.score` to be stored as

```
int var1 = ScoreActivity.score
```

But the next time the user goes through the game and gets a score, I would like the `ScoreActivity.score` to be stored as

```
int var2 = ScoreActivity.score
```

Moreover, I would like the value in `var1` to remain as the first ScoreActivity.score. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Sounds like you want an ArrayList?  Then just have `ArrayList scores` array and `scores.add(ScoreActivity.score)`.

Comment: @Uxonith but how would I keep the `ArrayList` from refreshing after the app closes and restarts?

Comment: You need to store the scores to a file, or use a database

Comment: @etherous I was looking into `sharedPreferences`, but I have no idea how I would adapt it to my use, or if it was even a good idea for what I was doing.

Comment: Serialize the data at the appropriate times, then de-serialize it when the app starts again. JSON works. You could also go for the `singleton` approach so it's available throughout the entire app.

Comment: Have you looked over the Android tutorials on [Saving Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) and [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, in plain Java (Nothing related to Android storage in your app, I can't really say much about that because I've never tried doing it so far.), I see a few ways of doing this.

- First, you can use a simple array if you know how many scores you will have.  You only need to check how much you filled your array so far each time you want to insert a new value.
- Another solution would be to look at the Java Collection interface, and all the main classes implementing it. You could get great use of those in this case, especially if you need to order the scores later on. [Javadoc of Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)
- Otherwise, you could just use a String and separate the elements with a character, and add a score each time.  For example:
  `String scores = score1 + "|" + score2 + "|" + ScoreActivity.score;`
  You would only have to parse the text with a regex to get the right information.  Of course it's not the best to order the information inside.

Other people may give better advice about storing it in an app, but this is basically the ways I would do it in Java.  I would personally head for the second one, with the Collections.

Hope that helps!

Edit: As someone said, you could either use a database to store your data, or put it in a file.  This makes a fourth solution, where you can put your data (encrypted or not, it's up to you) in a file, and retrieve it later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the app closing and restarting, and somehow restoring the score for particular activity, you'll probably want to use some persistent storage.

It's a little unclear exactly your parameters, but assume each session that a user goes through ScoreActivity generates a unique score, which you want tied to a specific activity, you can store the value in SharePreferences and retrieve it later when you start the activity with a particular identifier.

Reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

So you'd basically be storing a KV pair like { "scoreSession1", 10 }.

Comment: Do you think "SharedPreferences" is the way to store an untold amount of `score`s? I think it's best to reserve preferences for, well, *preferences*; at least I can't say I've seen it recommended as you do.

Comment: You can use it for other things besides preferences. See the link, and note their comment on the sidebar titled "User Preferences". It's a sufficient short term solution-- if benz wants to keep the entire history for display somewhere else, a different data storage solution might be better.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Yeah, I've read that. We can debate if that means a potentially large number of scores. I believe the gist of that statement is more along the lines of dynamic components that would differ by user and not large amounts of raw data. Your link says that as well.