# Singleton class returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, singleton

I have a Singleton class. When I try to access the instance of the class I get a NullPointerException.

Here is my code:-

Logout.java

```
private static Logout instance;
public Logout() {

    instance = this;
}
public static Logout getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
public void clearApplicationData() 
     {
       File cache = getCacheDir();
       File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
            }
        }
    }
}
 public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) 
    {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Main.java

```
Logout.getInstance.clearapplicationData();  //NullPointerException here
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Nowhere in the code you posted do I see you actually *create* a `Logout` instance (unless there is something Android-specific that should automatically create this or something along those lines)

Comment: You are probably calling `getInstance()` before the `onCreate()` method is ever called

Comment: @user2625086 It appears to be an Activity class. In that case, "onCreate" is not a constructor. Better create Simple java class.

Comment: Check your code of calling `onCreate()`

Comment: But where are you creating the instance? OnCreate is not a constructor!!

Comment: For reference take a look at [this singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964101/store-strings-as-different-variables-on-each-trial/23964416#23964416), you're kinda off track here. It should be complete enough to see where you're wrong. But for certain, if you want a singleton you'd better make the constructor private or all bets are off!

Comment: All the answers below should address your concerns, if you are not able to grasp it please get your basics right first.

Answer (score 3):

If `Logout` is not supposed to be an `Activity` create a simple java class and change getInstance function to:

```
public static Logout getInstance() {
    if(instance==null)
       instance = new Logout();  
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two basic things for a singleton:

- Private constructor
- Static instance variable to hold the reference to the single object

Easy and safe way to implement (with built-in lazy loading) is:

```
public class Logout {
private static Logout instance = new Logout();

private Logout () {    
}

public static Logout getInstance(){
   return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a java class like below and change your getinstance function like this,first check for null,if object is null then create a new object.

```
public class Logout {
private static Logout dataObject = null;

private Logout () {
    // left blank intentionally
}

public static Logout getInstance() {
    if (dataObject == null)
        dataObject = new Logout ();
    return dataObject;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either `Logout` or `Logout.getInstance` is returning null. Make sure it is not null

Answer (score 0):

1) Class is not singleton, constructor is public hence you can create as many instances as you wish, however last one (theortically) will be assigned ton instance

2) when you call getInstance you will get last instance created

3) you are not creating its instance anywhere hence nothing is assigned to instance hence you are getting null

For singleton following should be true

1) class must have private constructor

2) getInstance must be static and synchronized

3) for performance you can put synchronized in double check for nullability

4) you can create and assign instance in static block itself

5) in getInstance you check for instance being null, if null create new else return existing one

6) you can use new Enum style singleton

7) if class is serializable, implement readResolve

even after all this you might not be able to achieve true singleton because of class loaders or having application running on different JVMs in production

Answer (score -1):

Better do a null check before doing Logout.getInstance.clearapplicationData() as follows

```
if(Logout.getInstance.clearapplicationData() != null){
    Logout.getInstance.clearapplicationData();
}
```